# Average a single period of a periodic signal with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I made a measurement in university. The signal has a lot of noise, but is periodic.

[image: My raw signal]

I know know the point where the signal starts (x=36400) and what frequency (1Hz) and samplerate (48000) are. So I can "cut" single periods every 48000 points. I can produce arrays looking like this `[[period1],[period2],...,[period100]]`, where each period contains the measured values.

I now want to average over every single period to get a less noisy signal. I know how to do this with for-loops, but is there any fast way to use numpy for this?

Comment: hard to know without some sample data but if the period is commensurate with the array indices, should be able to reshape it.  Let's suppose you have 10 periods then len = 10 * 48000.  You can reshape: arr2 = arr.reshape(-1, 48000), which will give you a row for every period and a column for every point in the period, and then you can average along the rows using arr2.mean(axis=0) and get an averaged period.  If the data are not fully commensurate you may have to do something else.

Comment: It should be kinda commensurate with the indices. As you can see I have some flatline measurement in front and at the end of the signal. I used trial-and-error to cut off the beginning. But if I find the right index of the beginning,  would reshape(periods*48000, 48000) work?

Comment: reshape(-1, 48000) will work for any 1-D array that has n_periods * 48000 elements.  The -1 asks numpy to handle that automatically.  If you want to be explicit about it for some reason, then do reshape(n_periods, 48000)

Comment: As i told you, i have no signal at the end of my array. Its just a flatline and I dont want to add this to the averages. Thanks. You should put this into an answer, so I can mark it as done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want to slice your array to get the meaningful part

```
n_periods = 10  # or however man
beginning_idx = 1000  # or whever the good data begins

raw_signal = ...  # this is the data you read in
good_signal = raw_signal[beginning_idx:beginning_idx + n_periods * 48000]
periodic = good_signal.reshape(n_periods, 48000)
avg_signal = periodic.mean(axis=0)
```